# How to get a specific value from registry file into variable as a batch script

Tags: batch-file

First post here

I am working on deploying a specific .dll file (iprint.dll) into the end users IBM folder, so they are able to print. I am trying to make the script so it checks from the registry path, since the IBM Notes location can be installed in different locations. The path im looking at is the following.

1. KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lotus\Notes\9.0
2. VALUE_NAME=Path

If i do `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lotus\Notes\9.0" /v "Path"`

I get the following : Path    REG_SZ    C:\Lotus\Notes\

But i only want the data value C:\Lotus\Notes\

My end goal is to take the value and place in a variable that i can copy/install the iprint.dll to.

I am not an expert in this at all and what everything ive learned is from google searching.

So far i got the following, which is failing, what am i doing wrong and any suggestions?

```
@echo on

setlocal
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker
set SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS=1
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lotus\Notes\9.0"
set VALUE_NAME=Path

FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
    @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
    @echo Value Type = %ValueType%
    @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)

copy "iPrint.dll" %ValueValue%

endlocal
```

Comment: The exact syntax for this type of task has been posted thousands of times before on this site. ```@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lotus\Notes\9.0" /V "Path" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%%H```. Please use the search facility at the top of the page in future, before submitting questions, which have essentially been previously answered.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer.

I should have included this one, i have tried it and cant seem to get it to work.. I have tried a couple from stackoverflow including this one and ended up working with the one i posted.. 

The result i get is "%%G was unexpected at this time."

But removing one % seemed to have fixed it and the code is now running fine.

Comment: The one only way you'll get that result is if you run it at the Command Prompt. This is a [[tag:batch-file]] tagged question, so I provided a full one line batch file answer. If you wanted to test it in cmd.exe, you should have tagged your question [[tag:cmd]] and/or [[tag:command-prompt]], and I'd have made the minor change, ```For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lotus\Notes\9.0" /V "Path" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%H```.